# Android get items from sqlite db with date of today or previous

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I'm struggling with the implementation of dates in SQLite3 (for android). According to the documentation (https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html and http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), SQLite doesn't have datatypes for date and time specifically and therefore it can be either stored as a TEXT or as an INTEGER. I've tried both, but they give the same erroneous results. After reading a *lot* on the internet and trying everything I can think of, I come here as a last resort.

So, now for the problem. The idea is actually very simple. I have a table containing items, with a date column. Now I want to select all items from this database that have a date of today, or before (i.e. today or in the past). In my current implementation I store dates as integers, since most people seem to agree that that is the way to go.

Below is the (simplified) code for inserting an item.

```
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // Might not be necessary
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 4); // Today plus 4 days

SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COLUMN_DATE, calendar.getTimeInMillis()); // Today as integer/long
long id = db.insert(TABLE_ITEMS, null, values); // Add to db
```

And next I want to select the items where the date is equal to or lower than today:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TEXT, COLUMN_DATE};
String[] selectArg = new String[]{"date('now')"};
Cursor cItems = db.query(TABLE_ITEMS, columns, COLUMN_DATE + "<= ?", selectArg, null, null, null);
//Cursor cItems = db.query(TABLE_ITEMS, columns, "strftime('%Y-%m-%d'," + COLUMN_DATE + ")" + select, selectArg, null, null, null);
//Cursor cItems = db.query(TABLE_ITEMS, columns, "date(" + COLUMN_DATE + ")" + select, selectArg, null, null, null);
```

Now all rows are selected, also the rows with a date in the future. Could anyone tell me what I need to do differently?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I found out that sqlite stores date integers in seconds (is that correct?). So that would mean that value I put in the database should be `Math.round(calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000`, to get it in seconds right? But then it makes even less sence, since a date in milliseconds should always be larger than a date in seconds. Anyhow, I tried that, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: One small remark. I've also checked that the date stored in the database is actually correct (i.e. in the future) by using a SimpleDateFormat on the number stored in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the insights CL. gave me, I fixed some trivial errors I made.

Looking back at the SQLite documentation, I figured that there are two ways of storing a date without a time. A Julian day number or a date string `YYYY-MM-DD`. There is no readily available function to get a Julian day number in java/android, so therefore I chose to go back to the string format again.

A second, mistake I figured out just now is that the selectArgs are considered text and therefore, putting the `date('now', 'localtime')` in there won't work.

Below are the final scripts that do work.

```
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); // Might not be necessary
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 4); // Today plus 4 days

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COLUMN_DATE, dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime())); // Date as string


SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
long id = db.insert(TABLE_ITEMS, null, values); // Add to db
```

And to get the data back:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TEXT, COLUMN_DATE};
String[] selectArg = new String[]{};
Cursor cItems = db.query(TABLE_ITEMS, columns, COLUMN_DATE + "<= date('now', 'localtime')", selectArg, null, null, null);
```

CL., many thanks for your help! In the end it was so simple...

Answer (score 1):

Neither `date()` nor `strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` returns a date in your format.

To convert a date into the seconds format, you would have to use `strftime('%s', ...)`, and convert the resulting string into a number.

Comment: Okay, sounds reasonable! So, if I store the date in seconds, I can compare it with `strftime('%s', 'now')`? But in that case, won't it select only items that were placed before the current time? So not the items that are later today?

Comment: So you want to select all rows with a timestamp before the start of the day that is one day after the current day? Use [modifiers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: You're probably correct! But thanks to your previous answer I figured it would be easier to store it in strings after all. And then I realized a huge mistake with putting the `date('now')` in the selectArg. I posted the correct answer below. Thanks a lot for your help!